# Django: Filter objects by a range of two integers

Tags: django

I have a search form with id, price_from, price_to and drive_from, driven_too, but since price and driven are the same logic I am only focusing in one of these, since price_from and price_to are not in the model, it gives me an error because this parameter does not exist, therefore it can not compare anything.

How can i search in the car objects for an object which price is within this range (price_from - price_to), should i modify my model?

```py
# model
class Car(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.IntegerField()

# view
def search(request):
        if 'search_filter' in request.GET:
            search_params = request.GET.dict()
            search_params.pop("search_filter")
            price_from = search_params['price_from']
            price_to = search_params['price_to']
            q_list = [Q(("{}__icontains".format(param), search_params[param])) for param in search_params 
            if search_params[param] is not None]  

            my_query = Car.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, q_list))
            cars = [{
                'id': x.id,
                'driven': x.driven,
                'price': x.price,
            } for x in my_query
            ]
            return JsonResponse({'data': cars})
        context = {'cars': Car.objects.all().order_by('price')}
        return render(request, 'cars/car_index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct a `Q(..)` object with:

```
Q(price__gte=price_from, price__lte=price_to)
```

or you can *exclude* the bounds with:

```
Q(price__gt=price_from, price__lt=price_to)
```

although it is possible that `price_from` or `price_to` is `None`, and thus construct a `Q` object with kwargs:

```
if 'search_filter' in request.GET:
    search_params = request.GET.dict()
    search_params.pop('search_filter')
    price_from = search_params.pop('price_from', None)
    price_to = search_params.pop('price_to', None)
    q_list = [
        Q(('{}__icontains'.format(k), v))
        for k, v in search_params.items()
        if v is not None
    ]
    price = { 'price__gte': price_from, 'price__lte': price_to }
    q_list.append(Q(**{k: int(v) for k, v in price.items() if v is not None}))
    # ...
```

Comment: This is great, but still for instance if i am searching for a car that costs within the range of 10 000 to 20 000 dollars, it will show me all the cars within that range but also the cars that contains 10 000 or 20 000 in price.

Comment: Might be easier to use a [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#range) if the bounds are inclusive.

Comment: @SachihiroTakamori: you can exclude the bounds with `__lt` instead of `__lte` and `__gt` instead of `__gte`.

Comment: @Saysa: yes, but then we of course loose the flexibility of "*half bounded intervals*".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry i did not explain very clearly, it also shows me the cars that costs 110 000 or 120 000

Comment: @SachihiroTakamori: what if you use `int(..)`s?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem found a bug that the search works only for the price now and not for any other parameters, car_type for instance

Comment: @SachihiroTakamori: what is the content of the `q_list` before you construct the query?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `"GET /cars/search_car/?search_filter=true&car_type=ford&price_from=0&price_to=10000&search_filter=true HTTP/1.1" 200 12` Get request and  `[<Q: (AND: ('car_type__icontains', 'ford'))>)>]` and the q_list

Comment: @SachihiroTakamori: there is something strange here, at the of the url, it shows: `&price_to=10000search_filter=true`, so it looks like GET parameters are "mixed up".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it has `&` in middle, its my mistake, and search is a form with car_type, car_make, price_from, price_to, driven_from, driven_to

Comment: @SachihiroTakamori: when I process this with the given querystring, I get `[<Q: (AND: ('car_type__icontains', 'ford'))>, <Q: (AND: ('price__gte', 0), ('price__lte', 10000))>]`, so this seems correct, the `q_list` of course then should be transformed into a query, like you already wrote in your question.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the problem as i see, is that this part `<Q: (AND: ('price__gte', 0), ('price__lte', 10000))>` does not show at all in my query.

Comment: @SachihiroTakamori: well the `reduce(..)` step transforms it to `<Q: (AND: ('car_type__icontains', 'ford'), ('price__gte', 0), ('price__lte', 10000))>` here. It might help to use a debugger and see how the system obtains this result.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem found it, the problem was that i had to put the default values as 0, because i could not let the be empty "" and the price dict was looking for cars that was gte: 0 and lte: 0, i do apologize for being so stupid but at least i learned something, cheers. :)